# Access to Django Session with React

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, django-sessions

I'm new to React and I wanna Access my **Django sessions** with **React framework**.
In this case I have an array in my session named `UserInfo` that I can access with `request.session['UserInfo']` in Django.
I wanna know how can I get `UserInfo` data in React side and work with it? 
Literally how can we get or pass data from frontend to backend between these two?

Comment: You can not access session variables, or at least not directly, you will need an API to retrieve these. session variables are stored at the server-side, and normally used for sensitive data you don't want to expose to the client.

Comment: So the only way is request to django side and get server response with session data?

Comment: well why is this stored in the session variables in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access session variables, or at least not directly, you will need an API to retrieve these. session variables are stored at the server-side, and normally used for sensitive data you don't want to expose to the client.

You could thus make a small view that we can use to fetch the data:

```
def user_info(request):
    return JsonResponse({'data': request.session.get('UserInfo')})
```

and then work with an AJAX request, to fetch the data.

But be careful! Don't create a view that can retrieve an arbitrary key:

```
# don't do this!!

def session_info(request, key):
    return JsonResponse({'data': request.session.get(key)})
```